# Is a nested std::transform inefficient?

Tags: c++, performance, stl-algorithm

If I have a `std::string`:

```
std::string s{"hello"};
```

and a loop that modifies it in-place, like this:

```
for (auto &c: s)
  c = std::toupper(c);
```

I can replace it with the equivalent `transform`:

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
               [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char 
               { return std::toupper(c); });
```

and these snippets generate identical [assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/w8GsYm). They also have similar [performance](http://quick-bench.com/oXg_a-Ak7lWlAPinBAJ-46Lt2gs).

However, if I have a `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
std::vector<std::string> v {"hello", "how", "are", "you"};
```

and modify it in-place like this:

```
for (auto & s : v)
  for (auto &c: s)
    c = std::toupper(c);
```

the equivalent transform should be:

```
std::transform(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(v),
  [](auto s) {
    std::transform(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::begin(s), 
      [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::toupper(c); });
    return s;
});
```

However, the `transform` version generates over half as much [assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/e8aBLP), and [performs](http://quick-bench.com/SKBPB0kVSjrGl0WZaV9xEqT96ko) correspondingly poorly, which is surprising to me.

Is `std::transform` not a zero-cost abstraction in this case, or am I just using it incorrectly?

Comment: Did you mean to say `[](auto& s) {` in that last snippit of code?  Without the reference param, you are effectively making a copy of that string.

Comment: Is it any different when using `unsigned char` in the loop version as you do in the other?

Comment: @selbie Actually I tried that, and it reduced a few lines of assembly, and had no change really in performance.

Comment: @cigien -- Actually, adding the reference `[](auto& s)` does slightly improve the performance.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie True, but it's still a big [difference](http://quick-bench.com/gmoUQdttNbcFt0ee8RmufX6wprY)

Comment: @chris It doesn't let me bind to `unsigned char`, but I tried `char` and there was no difference.

Comment: The `std::transform` version also more than doubles the amount of code necessary, and is harder to read and understand.  I'm not sure I see the appeal.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner That's a reasonable view, but it's subjective, and besides the point. Anyway, `ranges::transform` would be much easier on the eyes, and I'm *assuming* it works similarly to `transform`.

Comment: My guess is that the compiler authors can easily see what can be optimized using the simple range based `for`, not so with nested `std::transform` calls.

Comment: How are you benchmarking all this?  Without understanding that, everything suggested is mostly speculative.

Comment: @selbie There are links to quickbench in the question. Is that sufficient?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That would appear to be the case. Shame. Is there anything in principle preventing the optimizations, or is it just a QOI issue?

Comment: No principle really.  Just that the current optimization strategy maybe is not able to detect this.  Not to say it can't be done in a future version.

Comment: If you're taking a reference now as per selbie's answer, what's the point of the outer `transform` anyway? Just use `for_each`... or better, a loop.

Comment: @Veedrac I'm just investigating how `transform` works, or can be made to work. In this particular case, a loop would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass and return everything by reference.  Otherwise, you make multiple copies of the string.   Notice the change: `[](auto& s) -> std::string& {`

```
std::transform(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(v),
  [](auto& s) -> std::string& {
    std::transform(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::begin(s), 
      [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::toupper(c); });
    return s;
});
```

I added two new quickbench functions to your link.  One which takes the input string as pass by reference.  And the other that also returns by reference.  That is:

```
static void Transform2(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code before the loop is not measured

  std::vector<std::string> v {"hello", "how", "are", "you"};
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::transform(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(v),
    [](auto& s) {
      std::transform(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::begin(s), 
        [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::toupper(c); });
      return s;
    });

  }
}
BENCHMARK(Transform2);


static void Transform3(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code before the loop is not measured

  std::vector<std::string> v {"hello", "how", "are", "you"};
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::transform(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(v),
    [](auto& s) -> std::string& {
      std::transform(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::begin(s), 
        [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::toupper(c); });
      return s;
    });

  }
}
BENCHMARK(Transform3);
```

Depending on how lucky I get when I run the benchmark, Transform3 is nearly (and sometimes equal) in perf to the InPlace test implementation.

[image]

Comment: That did it, identical assembly(almost), and identical [performance](http://quick-bench.com/7HbgoszuqQx9zXlt3EveHtSnTYY) now. Phew, weight off my mind.

Comment: Thanks for the additional benchmarks, they're very helpful.